# Problem changing root and not changing page after that in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I have a notification module ,in that module i should redirect user to other pages for showing notification detail .

I have a problem with this :

when i enter this route `payment/detail/1254` for first time , every thing is ok , but then i need to change route to this for show other notification detail `payment/detail/8547` , the route changes , but the page not change not show me previous detail .

i know i can use this code in every component i need :

```
  router.events.subscribe((val) => {
    // see also 
    console.log(val instanceof NavigationEnd) 
});
```

but i have a more than 40 modules . i want use the this code in common place , i need write this code or same code in the common place and I do not have this problem every time the route changes.

**how can i solve this problem ???**

Comment: would you mind building a https://www.stackbit.com/ minimal example showing the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Problem: you navigate from **route** A to **route** A with different parameters. this causes the router to not do anything, by default, as you're navigating to the same page.

Possible solutions:

One approach would be to subscribe to `ActivatedRoute`'s `paramMap` and fetch the details every time it emits.
preferably piped with `distinctUntilChanged()` to avoid reloading the page when navigating to same page with same parameter.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap
     .pipe(distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev.id === curr.id))
     .subscribe(({id}) => this.getDetails(id));
}
```

a Different approach would be to configure your router to reload when navigating to the same route.

```
     @NgModule({
       imports: [
           RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })
       ],
       exports: [RouterModule],
     })
```

This obviously might add a performance hit, depending on your architecture.